# Vue 3 pass props from parent to child of child

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

So I want to achieve what the title says. Let's say I have this structure:

`parent -> child -> secondChild`

Now, I have a variable in the parent called `isActive` for example. I know I can do it like this:

```
parent.vue

<child :active="isActive" />
```

```
child.vue

<template>
<secondChild :active="props.active"
</template>


<script setup>

const props = defineProps(['active'])

</script>
```

```
secondChild.vue

<template>
{{isActive}}
</template>


<script setup>

const props = defineProps(['active'])

</script>
```

So this can work yeah. But this wont be nice if I have 10 components nested in each other. How could I do this good without using `pinia` or `vuex`

Thanks

Comment: Provide/inject. But global store is more straightforward if you don't expect to have concurrent hierarchies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you use `provide/inject`:

https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html

```
parent.vue

<script setup>
import {provide} from 'vue';

provide('active', isActive);
</script>

<template>
<child />
</template>
```

```
child.vue

<template>
<secondChild />
</template>
```

secondChild.vue

```
<template>
<secondChild />
</template>


<script setup>

import {inject} from 'vue';

const isActive = inject('active', ref(false));

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own [Vue 3 State Management](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api) file.

```
// stores/active.js

import { ref } from 'vue'

export const isActive = ref(false)
```

Then in any component, you can import it and use it like the following.
Note that the variable is going to be reactive in all of them since we are setting it through `ref`...and you can also use `reactive`, `computed` and so on here):

```
// component.vue

<script setup>
import { isActive} from '/stores/active'

// isActive.value is reactive
</script>

<template>
 <!-- isActive is reactive -->
 {{ isActive }}
</template>
```

Although this works, it is very important to state that in a scenario where this would be shared by 10+ components, the best approach indeed would be to use [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/).

Comment: This will make each of 10+ components to receive its own state

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you need something like React's Context API to avoid prop drilling. You can use the [Provide/Inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html) option. You can import `provide` from `vue` and use it in your ancestor component for defining your data and use `inject` to inject that data into your child component. The schema of your parent component may look like this:

```js
<template>
  <Provide>
    <div>
      <ChildComponent />
      <div>
         <AnotherChildComponent />
      </div>
    </div>
  </ProvideUserSettings>
</template>
```

which in every `ChildComponent` you can have another component that needs that data